# Binding an int property to a string bindableProperty

Tags: c#, maui

I have a custom view with a string bindable property like this:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty QuantityProperty =
   BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Quantity), typeof(string), typeof(NumberChoseView), "1");

    public string Quantity
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(QuantityProperty);
        set => SetValue(QuantityProperty, value);
    }
```

> This property will be used as the Text of a label.

Then I have an object like this:

```cs
public class OrderObject
{
    public int OrderQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'm gonna use the custom view in a page and have the `DataType` of the page as the `OrderObject` so that I can bind the `OrderQuantity` property into the `Quantity` property of the custom view.

```xml
<views:NumberChoseView Quantity="{Binding OrderQuantity}" />
```

But this doesn't work, is it that the int property is not automatically converted into string?
If so, is there a way to convert it when binding or should i just use the OrderQuantity in the OrderObject as a string?

Edit:

I now changed the Quantity type to Int and it says now that when I do the binding `<views:NumberChoseView Quantity="{Binding OrderQuantity}" />`

The `OrderQuantity` is not found in `NumberChoseView`:

```
Int32   'OrderQuantity' property not found on 'RestaurantOnTableOrderingApp.Templates.Views.NumberChoseView', target property: 'RestaurantOnTableOrderingApp.Templates.Views.NumberChoseView.Quantity'
```

I add that the custom view is used inside a `CollectionView.ItemTemplate` with the `ItemSource` set with a `IEnumerable<OrderObject>`

Comment: Why does Quantity need to be a string?

Comment: The natural solution would be to build an IntToString converter and refer to that in your Binding. However, I agree with Jason's question... why would you design Quality to be a string? Because, either (1) Quality should be changed to an int as well, OR (2) Quality should be changed to a type that can accept both a string or an int, such as an object.

Comment: Yes @Jason is right, I thought that it wouldn't convert int to string cause Text accepts strings but I was wrong

Comment: You can accept your own answer. This may help others in the future.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT it said that i could accept it in 2 days, I'm waiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed all this by using Quantity as an Int and by deleting the line in the NumberChoseView `BindingContext="{x:Reference self}"`.

Didn't know the problem was here.